# Dynamically Change An Elements CSS from Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Project - https://c9.io/mikethedj4/mmd/workspace/index.html

So I'm working on an experimental WYSIWYG website designer, and ran into some trouble today.

I'm grabbing a unknown elements class with the following...

`$('.findclassname').val($(this).attr('class'));`

I'm grabbing it's position with the following...

```
if ($(this).css('position') === 'static') {
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
}

if ($(this).css('position') === 'absolute') {
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
}

if ($(this).css('position') === 'fixed') {
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}
```

After the class and position have been grabbed I'm trying to change the grabbed value to a new one with the following...

```
$('.grab-pos-static').click(function() {
  $($('.findclassname').val()).css({
    'position': 'static'
  });
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
});

$('.grab-pos-absolute').click(function() {
  $($('.findclassname').val()).css({
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
});

$('.grab-pos-fixed').click(function() {
  $($('.findclassname').val()).css({
    'position': 'fixed'
  });
  $('.grab-pos-static').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-absolute').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-pos-fixed').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
});
```

Unfortunately this is dynamically changing the elements position value.

Is there any other way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

~Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not grabbing the position correctly. When you call `.css()` with two arguments, it sets the style, it doesn't compare it. It should be:

```
if ($(this).css('position') == 'static') {
```

In your code to change the position, you're not using the correct selector. It should be:

```
$("." + $('.findclassname').val()).css({
    'position': 'absolute'
});
```

Note that the way you're doing this will only work if elements have just one class. If elements have more than one class, `$(this).attr("class")` will return all the classes as a space-separated string, and that won't work correctly in the selector.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't dynamically change the elements position. 

Do you know if there's an easier way to select/change the elements position rather than doing this... `$($('.findclassname').val()).css({});`.

Comment: lol way to make me fee like an idiot lol. I can't believe I didn't think of that